# I want extended property values as columns name

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

First of all I'm new in sql.
Now I'm using mssql .
I have 6 table each table have 4 to 6 column .
they all have extended properties.
I want `sys.extendedproperties.values` as all columns name
how can i do that ?
is that possible

```
SELECT  *
FROM sys.extended_properties
```

| class | class_desc | major_id | minor_id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OBJECT_OR_COLUMN | 245575913 | 1 | MS_Description | recore year |
| 1 | OBJECT_OR_COLUMN | 245575913 | 2 | MS_Description | customer id |

that's example of extended property

| year | id | name | createdate | renewdate | rowid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 1 | neo | 2020-09-12 21:50:00 | 2020-09-12 21:50:00 | F2265B9B-FA3C-4D01-A3E2-E0C8B7068391 |
| 52 | 2 | BBB | 2020-09-12 21:50:00 | 2020-09-12 21:50:00 | 1637A361-BF1B-4EDB-B40C-92B3A9CCFD9E |

this is one of my table.

I want to show **year** as **record year**

**id** as **customer id**

**name** as something .

I just want to change as alias in C# datagridview.
Is that possible.

Sorry for my grammer

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. From what I can decipher, after you have bound the table to the grid, each column in the grid has a `HeaderText` property. This will allow you to change the text in the column headers. I am guessing this is what you are looking for? It is also possible to this in the sql query using an alias.

Comment: datagridview is connected to sql server. like databinding. So I think I don't have header text .To connect I used Select * From Table .I think if alias can use It will be changed but I don't know how

Comment: If the grid has a column… then that column has a `HeaderText` property. If you want to change the name in the query, it may go something like… `SELECT DBColName1 AS TableColName1, DBColName2 AS TableColName2…` …Etc.

Comment: so I have to use alias 6 times for 6 tables.Is that any eazy way .all table is selected by combobox .some tables' column name is not have on another table.

Comment: Well… if you find it not “eazy” to rename the tables and/or columns in the query or in code, you can always change the table and/or column names in the DB. Pick your poison.

Comment: Yep I known ,and I can't change .Sorry

Comment: Hmm... not sure what you are "sorry" for. If you _"can't change"_ ...  then what is your question?

Comment: I can't change table 's column name in DB .But I can use alias or whatever to show in datagridview .There is 6 table in DB.  I use `"SELECT  * FROM [dbo].["+comboBox1.Text+"]" ; `.Every tables' name is in combobox. Each table has different column names .My question is **Can I use something instead of * ?**.You said  ` SELECT DBColName1 AS TableColName1, DBColName2 AS TableColName2… `  but tables have different column names.TableColName1 is not in table2.That's my problem.

Comment: Well. “DEPENDING” on “which” table is “selected” in the combo box, will dictate “which” query to use. There will be a different query for each table. Using… `SELECT  * FROM [dbo].["+comboBox1.Text+"]` is convenient and also UNSAFE, but it won’t work for what you want to do. Make six (6) different query methods, and call the appropriate one depending on which table is selected.

Comment: Thanks .May be there is no way with one line. Thank you .

Comment: If you can come up with a way to use the same code to produce six different queries… then you would make life a lot easier for many people. `SELECT *` will select all the columns `From [dbo].["+comboBox1.Text+"].` … I do not know “why” you would think that there is some “magic” that would “change” the column names “automatically” to the names you want. I mean no disrespect; however, I do suggest you do more research on sql queries. This is fairly basic stuff.

Comment: As the answer shows, changing the column names is “usually” (preferred) done in the query. If you do this in the query, then that is less coding you have to do in the UI (grid). If you leave the query as it is, then your code is going to have to change this either in the table or the UI (grid). Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

in c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT MyTable.year AS [record year],MyTable.id AS [customer id],MyTable.name AS [something],MyTable.createdate,MyTable.renewdate,MyTable.rowid " +
      "FROM sys.tables AS MyTable WHERE NAME = 'extended_properties'", connstring);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds, "MyTable");
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTable"].DefaultView;
}
```

sql command

```
SELECT MyTable.year AS [record year],MyTable.id AS [customer id],MyTable.name AS [something],MyTable.createdate,MyTable.renewdate,MyTable.rowid FROM sys.tables AS MyTable WHERE NAME = 'extended_properties'
```

Comment: sorry . I want `sys.extendedproperties`   value as all columns name.That's not work.

Answer (score 0):

an example from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5384/working-with-sql-server-extended-properties/:

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(tables.schema_id) AS SchemaName,
       tables.name                   AS TableName,
       cols.name                     AS ColumnName,
       ep.name                       AS ExtendedPropertyName,
       CAST(ep.value AS sql_variant) AS ExtendedPropertyValue
FROM sys.tables AS tables
         INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS cols
                    ON cols.object_id = tables.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS ep
                    ON ep.major_id = tables.object_id AND
                       ep.minor_id = cols.column_id AND
                       ep.class = 1
```